# Installed then uninstalled Kubuntu, which changed some themes that can't be unchanged anymore

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, themes

On a normal Ubuntu installation, I installed kubuntu-desktop recently to check it out. I ended up really not liking it so I uninstalled it again. However, it seems by installing it the first time it made some style changes that I cannot change back. The most annoying of which is a couple white windows with gray text on them. It appears in Gnome Terminal, the top bar in Tilix, and some backgrounds like in Gnome Tweaks, all shown in the screenshot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzFV0.png]

I've changed my Themes in these programs and system-wide multiple times, but these unreadable chunks never change. I can avoid the issue in Terminal by not using the  system theme, but the same setting doesn't work in Tilix and it causes problems in a variety of other apps. Why is it this difficult to uninstall a secondary desktop environment? KDE seems like a permanent mistake that keeps haunting me.

Comment: This is a general experience: It usually works to add a desktop environment (e.g. kubuntu-desktop or lubuntu-desktop) but it is often creates problems to remove a desktop environment. So it is a good idea to test advanced things like adding a desktop environment separately in a live system or in a separate installed operating system that is dedicated for testing. (You can have a live system in a USB pendrive or in a virtual machine; and an installed system alongside your main system (in its own partition) or in a USB pendrive or in a virtual machine.)